# Force Mathematica to interpolate on non-structured tensor grid (n-dimensional)

Tags: interpolation, wolfram-mathematica

[Force Mathematica to interpolate on non-structured tensor grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242972/force-mathematica-to-interpolate-on-non-structured-tensor-grid)
I was interested in what I have to change in the code to make it work for n variables(not only for x, y).The data is represented in {{x,y,a,b,c,d,e,f},z}
The data I have is

```
 {
{{6,1333,81,172,36,9.4,1900,1590},1090},
{{6,1331,81,172,36,9.4,1900,1580},1100},
{{7,1314,80,172,36,10,1800,1570},200},
{{8,1297,79,171,36,11,1800,1560},300},
{{8,1279,78,171,36,12,1800,1540},400},
{{9,1262,77,170,36,13,1800,1520},500},
{{10,1244,76,170,35,13,1700,1500},600},
{{11,1225,75,169,35,14,1700,1480},700},
{{12,1205,74,168,35,15,1700,1460},800},
{{13,1185,73,168,35,16,1700,1440},900},
{{15,1164,72,167,34,17,1600,1410},2000},
{{16,1141,71,166,34,18,1600,1380},100},
{{18,1118,70,165,34,19,1600,1350},200},
{{20,1093,69,164,33,20,1500,1320},300},
{{23,1067,67,164,33,21,1500,1300},400},
{{25,1039,66,163,32,22,1500,1270},500},
{{29,1009,64,163,32,23,1400,1230},600},
{{33,976,63,162,31,24,1400,1190},700},
{{40,939,61,161,31,25,1400,1140},800},
{{52,896,58,161,30,25,1300,1070},900},
{{95,836,55,160,28,26,1200,969},3000}
}
```